# Different performance when same code is put in separate script and executed with execfile

Tags: python, neural-network, built-in, biological-neural-network

I have a script `network.py` that includes the following:

```
from brian import *
. . .
simulation_clock = Clock(dt=dt)
. . .
pop_vector = NeuronGroup(1, model=eqs_pop_vector)
```

This script raises a `TypeError`, because `simulation_clock` is not passed as an argument to `NeuronGroup`.

However, if I split up my code as follows

```
$ cat simclock.py
simulation_clock = Clock(dt=dt)
$ cat network.py
from brian import *
. . .
execfile('simclock.py')
. . .
pop_vector = NeuronGroup(1, model=eqs_pop_vector)
```

it runs without a hitch -- i.e., no `TypeError`.

The answer to my question may in part have to do with the particulars of `NeuronGroup`, but it's also more general than that: Why, in general, would the *same exact code* -- in this case, `simulation_clock = Clock(dt=dt)` -- have a different effect when separated from the rest of the code and called with `execfile` than when in the same script as the rest of the code?

With regard to the particulars of `NeuronGroup`, the following function is called (with the default keyword arguments) when no `Clock` is supplied as an argument, in order to find defined instances of `Clock`:

```
def find_instances(instancetype, startlevel=1, all=False):
    """Find first instances of a given class in the stack
    
    See documentation for module Brian.magic
    """
    # Note that we start from startlevel+1 because startlevel means from the calling function's point of view 
    for level in range(startlevel + 1, len(getouterframes(currentframe()))):
        objs, names = get_instances(instancetype, level, all=all)
        if len(objs):
            return (objs, names)
    return ([], [])
```

For some reason this function cannot find instances of `Clock` defined in separate files called with `execfile`.  So I guess this is a bug in `brian` that raises a general question.

Comment: Is it possible that there is more than one `Clock` class. When you import everything using `*` instead of being explicit, sometimes you override other classes. I would try only importing the things you need from the `brian` module and any other module you are using.

Comment: Totally agree.  I never import everything; this is code I was given by someone else.  There is only one `Clock` class, so that doesn't explain this.  The problem seems to have to do with `NeuronGroup`'s ability to find instances of `Clock`.  There is a function `find_instances` that `NeuronGroup`'s `__init__` calls that searches the stack for instances.  I'll post an answer once I've gotten to the bottom of this (if someone else hasn't beaten me to it).